# When I launched browser through cypress I don't see the icons in my web application

Tags: browser, icons, cypress

In regular Google Chrome browser I can see icons in my web application.
When I run Cypress and launch Chrome browser I can't see icons. Please see picture  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx2sn.jpg)

Comment: This is just a wild guess are you using `cy.reload(true)` in your tests. If yes, can you remove that and try again.

Comment: No. I don't use cy.reload(true)